# DownloadManager or DownloadManager + IntentService

Tags: android, intentservice, android-download-manager

In the case of using `DownloadManager` system service; some people creating an `IntentService` and then inside the `onHandleIntent` method, they call `DownloadManager.Request`:

```
public class DownloadService extends IntentService {
...    

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(...);
        request.setNotificationVisibility(...);
        ...
        ((DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE)).enqueue(request);
    }
...
}
```

And whenever they want to download a file, they call `startService`.

What is the benefit of that? Why we don't just use `DownloadManger` directly?! (without `IntentService`)

Comment: I dont know these people and i just use DownloadManager directly.

Comment: Running in a service is a better choice as it will run even if the current activity is killed or the app is in background.

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments.